# Laptop gets stuck on dell logo

Tags: boot, laptop, freeze, post

I have a Dell Inspiron 11 3000 laptop. Haven't used it in a while, now I tried booting up and it freezes at the dell logo. I removed all external peripherals, removed the WLAN card, and disconnected the hard drive. Nothing doing. No error codes, no beeps; the power LED (the only LED the laptop has) just peacefully fades out after a moment. When I removed the RAM to give it a nudge and see what happens, it protested loudly with the normal 2 beeps for RAM error.

Is it a goner or can it still be fixed? Anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: How long did you let it set at the logo screen?

Comment: @Moab, thanks for your response. After letting the power dissipate for a long while, I gave it on more try. It's alive and kicking now!